# Conditional if registration date in strtotime is more than x months logic

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I want to show a message if a user has been registered for longer than x months.

I intended to do this by getting the registered date and current date using `strtotime` and then seeing if the registered date is less than the current date minus the months.

Outcome of the below is 'Registered for more than 3 months' but the registered date is less than 3 months.

Feel free to rearrange the logic if it helps to find an answer.

```
<?php

$registered_date = strtotime( date( 'ymd', strtotime('2017-04-01 10:39:45') ) );
$current_date = strtotime( date( 'ymd' ) );
$months = '3';
$current_date_minus_months = strtotime( '-' . $months . ' months' , $current_date);

echo '<p>Registered Date: ' . $registered_date . '</p>';
echo '<p>Current Date: ' . $current_date . '</p>';
echo '<p>Current Date Minus Months: ' . $current_date_minus_months . '</p>';

if ( $current_date_minus_months < $registered_date ) {
    echo '<p>Registered for more than 3 months</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Registered for less than 3 months</p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Show us full output please.

Comment: This is everything...?

Comment: If `$current_date_minus_months` is __less__ then `$registered_date` then how on earth you can tell that user registered more than 3 months? How?

Comment: I appreciate the logic may be out... I am here for assistance with the right logic to use for this scenario too.

Comment: That's why instead of timestamps you should output human readable dates. If `$registered_date` is `April 1st` and `$current_date_minus_months` is `January 1st` and `January 1st` is __less__ then `April 1` - then why does you output `more than 3 months`?

Comment: If you mean '2017-04-01 10:39:45' unfortunately that is a database field I am reading the value from which can't be changed.

Comment: It seems you don't understand. So I'll tell you last time - if date of register is __bigger__ than date minus three months, it means that user registered less than 3 months, __less__ not __more__ like you output in your code. Understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first line of core already gives the first problem:

```
$registered_date = strtotime( date( 'ymd', strtotime('2017-04-01 10:39:45') ) );
```

The following code:

```
date('ymd', strtotime('2017-04-01 10:39:45'))
```

Results in  `170401`. Then  you feed this  to `strtotime()`  again. This
probably gets  parsed as 17:04:01,  meaning 5pm  of today in  your local
timezone. The truth is: `strtotime`  already converts to Unix timestamp,
so there is  no point in converting a date  string (2017-04-01 10:39:45)
to this format, then convert it back  with `date` and then back again to
Unix with another `strtotime` call.

Then, you also have a reversed logic: if the current date minus 3 months
event happens  equal of after the  registered date, that means  the user
registration is 3 months or longer. But this line states the opposite:

```
if ( $current_date_minus_months < $registered_date ) {
```

Either use `>=` or switch the variables around.

Also, the only  point in saving the  current date is that you  use it in
your calculation for 3 months ago.  But using the current time as second
parameter is the default, so you don't need that.

Cleaning up your code, we have this:

```
<pre><?php

$months = 3;

$registered_date = strtotime('2017-04-01 10:39:45');
$current_date_minus_months = strtotime("-$months months");

# for your debugging
print_r([
    'registered_date'      => $registered_date,
    'current_date'         => time(),
    'current_minus_months' => $current_date_minus_months,
]);

if ( $registered_date < $current_date_minus_months )
    echo "Registered for more than 3 months\n";
else
    echo "Registered for less than 3 months\n";
```

Anyway, a  much better approach  to this  is to use  the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php)
interface, object  oriented, as described  in the other answer.  Here is
another way of doing it:

```
$months = 3;

$current    = new DateTime();
$registered = new DateTime('2017-01-01 10:39:45');
$threshold  = $current->sub(new DateInterval('P' . $months . 'M'));

if ($registered <= $threshold)
    echo "more or equal to $months months";
else
    echo "less than $months months";
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, it has really helped understand this better. I also see how your DateTime version of the answer works for days like my comment on the earlier answer. Fantastic.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm improving the DateTime a bit, will update the text :)

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge I updated the DateTime version now, I know it got longer but this will be a more reliable implementation, without fixed days per month count and avoid year problems. Also more descriptive, easier to maintain in my personal opinion.

Comment: Yes I was about to ask about the * 30, but I see now that has been changed. Brilliant answer, thanks again.

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge Thanks, glad to help. Yes initially I did that to avoid the year problem, since as you noticed capturing only months from the interval does not account for year change. Dealing with dates is always a complicated thing...many aspects to consider depending on the reach and goals of your program. Using fixed days for months might still be something to consider, since for example someone whose period runs over February would have registration time bonus before someone who registered in, say, July. What to use depends on what makes more cultural sense for you and your users :)

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge Did you define `$months`? Looks like the format went without it. Should be like P3M but went PM

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge 

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Php [`Datetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to work with dates. In your case it will look like this:

```
<?php

$registered_date = new Datetime('2017-04-01 10:39:45');
$current_date = new Datetime();
$months = '3';
$diff = $current_date->diff($registered_date);

echo '<p>Registered Date: ' . $registered_date . '</p>';
echo '<p>Current Date: ' . $current_date . '</p>';
echo '<p>Month diff: ' . $diff->m . '</p>';

if (  $diff->y > 0 || $diff->m >= $months) {
    echo '<p>Registered for more than 3 months</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Registered for less than 3 months</p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: There were a number of errors in the code e.g. your $curentDate and $regDate variables I had to fix. Once done it will show 'Registered for less than 3 months'... BUT if you change the registered_date to say 2015, it still says 'Registered for less than 3 months' so I don't think that is calculating correctly somewhere.

Comment: Fixed logical mistake in code. Try it and post result, if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks that works with the year change, but if I change the registered date to 2017-01-01 15:25:45 this echos 'less than' when the date is more than 3 months.

Comment: Yes, that's because of `>` condition comparing month count. If you need **3 month or more** use `>=` condition.